# Stop SE Linux from Enforcing on Android AOSP

Tags: android-source, selinux

I need to stop SE Linux from enforcing, from the earliest possible time in the Android boot sequence.

I had read that a kernel parameter of "selinux=0" would stop this.  It doesn't:

```
smarc_mx8mq:/ # cat /proc/cmdline                                                                                                      
selinux=0 console=ttymxc2,115200 earlycon=imxuart,0x30880000,115200 init=/init video=HDMI-A-1:1080x1920-32@60 androidboot.console=ttymxc0 androidboot.hardware=freescale androidboot.fbTileSupport=enable cma=1280M androidboot.primary_display=imx-drm firmware_class.path=/vendor/firmware transparent_hugepage=never loop.max_part=7 buildvariant=eng ...
smarc_mx8mq:/ # getenforce
Enforcing
```

What can I do to absolutely stop SE Linux from enforcing from the start of the boot sequence?  (I can have root shell access and I can change the kernel config or any other part of the AOSP build.)

Comment: Please fix typo in the title ```Encorcing``` to ```Enforcing```.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What can I do to absolutely stop SE Linux from enforcing from the start of the boot sequence? (I can have root shell access and I can change the kernel config or any other part of the AOSP build.)

I turn off selinux in `BoardConfig.mk` by setting:

```
BOARD_KERNEL_CMDLINE += androidboot.selinux=permissive
```

Then after building and target flashing`cat /proc/cmdline` shows `androidboot.selinux=permissive`:

```
hikey960:/ # cat /proc/cmdline
androidboot.hardware=hikey960 firmware_class.path=/vendor/firmware loglevel=15 efi=noruntime
overlay_mgr.overlay_dt_entry=hardware_cfg_enable_android_fstab androidboot.selinux=permissive
```

Comment: Thanks for actually saying where and how you set "androidboot.selinux=permissive". Everyone else (including Google) left out that critical bit of information as if it was obvious.

Comment: @lessthanoptimal No problem :) You might be interested in this project https://github.com/nkh-lab/aosp-devicemk-parser which builds a `*.mk` dependency tree and visualizes it, to make it easier to understand the whole configuration picture of the build process.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `androidboot.selinux=permissive` instead of `selinux=0`.

I've read that `androidboot.selinux=disabled` will work too.