# AOSP: Can't switch SELinux to permissive for emulator target

Tags: android, android-source, selinux

According to [source.android.com](https://source.android.com/security/selinux/implement#steps) switching SELinux to permissive mode can be done via setting:

```
BOARD_KERNEL_CMDLINE := androidboot.selinux=permissive
```

or

```
BOARD_BOOTCONFIG := androidboot.selinux=permissive
```

And it works well for HiKey960 devboard for `hikey960-userdebug` target (what was already discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65992376/5130269) but for AOSP standard emulator targets, like `aosp_x86-eng` or `aosp_car_x86-userdebug` it doesn't work, why?

Comment: Same issue targeting "lunch aosp_raven-userdebug"